# Configuring zend module to use finish

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to configure the finish function for module.php in zend, from what I understand you need to configure some sort of listener (in bootstrap I think) that will call the finish function and I can then execute code after its finished with the user request.

Can someone provide some example code to setup the module to call finish once it has finished the user request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in the `onBootstrap` method of your `Module.php` as the following:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, array($this, 'doSomething'));
}
```

and then define a function that `doSomething` in your `Module.php` as the following:

```
public function doSomething(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

You can also add some priority for the callback functions you want to execute if you attached more than one listener on the same event as the following:

```
$em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, array($this, 'doSomethingFirst'), 20);
$em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, array($this, 'doAnotherThingLater'), 10);
```

Higher priority values execute earliest. (Default priority is 1, and negative priorities are allowed.)

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to attach a listener to the event, as you've rightly noted the place to do that is in the `onBootstrap` method of your `Module` class. The following should get you started...

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, function ($e) {        
        // do something...
    });
}
```